# REST API request Flutter web CORS issue

Tags: api, rest, http, cors, flutter-web

I hope you are well

I have a problem with flutter web. I try to make an API REST request to **https://timeapi.io/api/TimeZone/zone?timeZone=Europe/Amsterdam** to get the time from a specific location but I get this error **XMLHttpRequest error** and when displaying the console in the browser, I get this error (image below)

[image]

After a few days of research, I know that it is CORS and I was able to test a few solutions but without success.

Here is what I could do:

```
 Future<void> _getCurrentDateTime() async {
    try {
      var url = Uri.https('timeapi.io', 'TimeZone/zone', {'timeZone': 'Europe/Amsterdam'});
      final headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE",
        "Origin": "https://localhost"
      };

      var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
      log('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
      log('Response body: ${response.body}');

      // return now;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

How to solve this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `/api/` as part of the url in line:

```dart
var url = Uri.https('timeapi.io', 'TimeZone/zone', {'timeZone': 'Europe/Amsterdam'});
```

If you notice the error on your console you will see that the URL that is printed is also missing the `api` in the URL.

Which in turn ends up in a 404, if you open https://timeapi.io/TimeZone/zone?timeZone=Europe/Amsterdam in the browser you'll find a 404 response.

Thus, the 404 doesn't contain CORS headers in the response, resulting in the CORS error you see on the browser console.

If you want to call https://timeapi.io/api/TimeZone/zone?timeZone=Europe/Amsterdam

The code should probably be

```dart
var url = Uri.https('timeapi.io', 'api/TimeZone/zone', {'timeZone': 'Europe/Amsterdam'});
```

Also, you may want to remove these headers as they're supposed to be sent from the backend and not the frontend. The following lines of code are redundant.

```dart
final headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE",
    "Origin": "https://localhost"
};
```

Comment: I've done what you told me, and i still get the same error **XMLHttpRequest**.